# jQuery toggle not work when the argument are functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm trying to use `toggle()` to complete my click events. In this case, I read the API, and use `toggle(function1, function2, ...)`. But it was weird. The tag a just hide when I click it, rather than execute those functions inside.

Here is my javascript code.

```
function clickMe(){
    $("#lime").toggle(
        function(){
            var names = document.getElementsByName("selectOne");
            var len = names.length;
            if (len > 0) {
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                    names[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        },function(){
            var names = document.getElementsByName("selectOne");
            var len = names.length;
            if (len > 0) {
                    var i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                        names[i].checked = false;
                    }
            }
        }
    ) ;      
}
```

And here is HTML code.

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickMe()" id="lime">selectAll</a>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectOne" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectOne" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectOne" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectOne" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectOne" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectOne" /><br />
  </form>
```

I'm waiting for the comments. Thanks advance!

Comment: This functionality has been removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I think this form of `toggle()` was removed in 1.9.

Comment: Sorry! I read the API in Chinese, it maybe too old. I user 1.9 and I read the authoritative API just now. So, is there anther function to replace toggle?

Comment: @user1550968 - *Another function*? Nope. You'll have to roll your own. For your particular case, it's pretty simple. I posted it as an answer below...

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/toggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This functionality has been removed in jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/#entry-longdesc).

Use this instead (works for older versions too):

```
$(function ($) {

    var inputs = $('input[name=selectOne]');

    $("#lime").click(function () {
        inputs.prop( 'checked', ! inputs.prop('checked') );
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3GQDU/

---

As pointed out by @Andre, if the first is checked by hand, it will then uncheck all. If that's not what you want, use this:

```
$(function ($) {

    var inputs = $('input[name=selectOne]'),
        flag = true;

    $("#lime").click(function () {
        inputs.prop( 'checked', flag );
        flag = ! flag;
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3GQDU/1/

Comment: The function need double clicks to trigger the events. Could it be improved?

Comment: @user1550968 - Just use `.dblclick` instead of `.click`.

Comment: That's not quite the behaviour in OP example. `prop()` will return for the 1st element only. If the first is checked by hand, it will then uncheck all.

Comment: @Andre - That's correct. The alternative is to use a flag. I figured this would suffice.

Comment: @JosephSilber Nope, I mean the function provided by you need double clicks.

Comment: @JosephSilber my apologize, your method is correct. I'm confused by myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var check = true;
    $("#lime").click(function(){
        $('input[name=selectOne]').prop('checked', check);
        check = !check;
    });
});
```

By doing this, you won't need the 'onclick' attribute in `#lime` element. Just remove it, and let jQuery bind the click handler for you. This is usually a good thing, as it separates structure and behaviour.

**Edit:**

If you need a function that reproduces old jQuery toggle behaviour, here's it:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.toggleHandlers = function(eventType){
        var i = 0;
        var handlers = $.makeArray(arguments).slice(1);
        return this.bind(eventType, function() {
            handlers[i].apply(this, arguments);
            if(i < handlers.length -1)
                i++;
            else
                i = 0;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The difference from jQuery toggle is that it gets one extra parameter (the first one), that is the event type. So, it works with events other than click. Call it as:

```
$("#myElement").toggleHandlers('click', handler1, handler2[, handler3]);
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andreortigao/j9MH2/

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution is useful, but I can't vote up with my lower reputation...

Comment: No problem, I made it for fun, and posted here for future reference.